# Check two objects of different classes

Tags: java

I have three classes:

1. Human
2. Father
3. Child.

Child class extends Father and Father extends Human.

I have created some instances of each class and stored them into a ArrayList.

Now I want to write a method to check if object father1 has the same field address(for example: "21 str Goodwin") as the Object child1 address field (instances of class Father and Child) and give this method to my ArrayList and print if any results was found.

How can I do this?

Let me add my code here for more clarity:

Human class:

```
  public class Om {
  String nume;
  String prenume;
  String cnp;

Om(String nume,String prenume,String cnp){
this.nume=nume;
this.prenume=prenume;
this.cnp=cnp;

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Numele omului: " + this.nume +"\n"+ "Prenumele omului: " + this.prenume   +"\n"+ "Cnp-ul omului: " + this.cnp + "\n" ;
}


}
```

Father class:

```
public class Parinte extends Om{
String domiciliu;
Parinte(String nume, String prenume, String cnp, String domiciliu){
    super(nume,prenume,cnp);
    this.domiciliu=domiciliu;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Numele parintelui: " + nume +"\n"+
            "Prenumele parintelui :" + prenume +"\n"+ 
            "Cnp-ul parintelui: " + cnp +"\n"+ 
            "Domiciliul parintelui: "+domiciliu+"\n"; 
}

}
```

Child class:

```
public class Copil extends Parinte {
int varsta;
Copil(String nume, String prenume, String cnp, String domiciliu, int varsta){
    super(nume,prenume,cnp,domiciliu);
    this.varsta=varsta;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Numele copilului: " + nume +"\n"+
            "Prenumele copilului :" + prenume +"\n"+ 
            "Cnp-ul copilului: " + cnp +"\n"+ 
            "Domiciliul compiluiui: "+ domiciliu +"\n"+
             "Varsta copilului: "+varsta+"\n";
}


}
```

My method to sort list alphabetical:

```
import java.util.*;

public class comparareNume implements Comparator<Om>{
public int compare(Om om1, Om om2){
    return om1.nume.compareTo(om2.nume);}


}
```

And my main class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Om om1=new Om("Dubolari", "Dragos", "2006004034120");
    Om om2=new Om("Andronachi","Andrei", "12591295967123");
    Parinte p1=new Parinte("Vreascu","Andy","5845289564684","Al. Cel Bun 13");
    Copil c1 = new Copil("Mamaliga","George","5942356874156","Al. Cel Bun 13", 15);
    List<Om> colectie = new ArrayList<Om>();
    colectie.add(om1);
    colectie.add(p1);
    colectie.add(c1);
    colectie.add(om2);

    comparareNume comparNume = new comparareNume();
    Collections.sort(colectie, comparNume);
    System.out.println(colectie);       
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FatherObj.getAddress().equals(ChildObj.getAddress())`

Example for `getAddress()` and field `address` inside of Child and Father

```
private String address = "21 str Goodwin"

public String getAddress() {
   return address;
}
```

Comment: yes, something like this. As i think i need to create getAddress method first?

Comment: can i put the getAddress() method only in Father class and Child class could inherit it? Reason to not double the code.

Comment: You can, though I'm not used to seeing getters and setters inherited

Comment: I agree it's unusual with setters, but why getters? Inheriting getters seems common.

Comment: @aliteralmind Just my personal experience, I don't see it very often. It was only an opinion, and like all opinions it means very little.

Answer (score 1):

Put a function like this into `Human`, which is set via the constructor (it could also be set via a setter, but doing so in the constructor allows for immutability).

```
public Human(String address)  {
   addr = address;
}
public String getAddress()  {
   return  addr;
}
```

This function is accessible to all sub-classes.

Then you can access it as suggested by @NappaTheSaiyan

Comment: i cant put this method in human cause human has not address field, so i think i better put it in father cause father and child has address and child can inherit it from there, or am i wrong?

Comment: I disagree. When any other type of human, such as a `Mother`, extends `Human`, that would require your `getAddress` function to be in multiple locations. An alternative would be to create a `Addressable` interface and declare the function there (`Father` and `Mother` would implement it), but either way, there should be a centralized place for this function, to avoid duplicate code. (If a `Human` has an address that's never used, just set it to `null`--you could even have an additional `hasAddress()` flag function. Something...) Putting the function in `Father` is a mistake in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, i understood you, that's a nice option.